# import libs depending on the target with Typescript

Tags: node.js, typescript, operating-system, target-platform

I have a typescript project that need socketcan. Currently i use:

```
can = require('socketcan');
```

but
1) its not an es6 like import (not really the problem)
2) If i want to execute this code against a target who dont support Can Bus it says:

```
Error: Cannot find module './socketcan'
```

I really want to know how i cant configure imports depending on OS using typescript. I just want to fake socketcan when i run the code on OSX (my dev env.)

What is the correct approach ?

Comment: Not sure if this would help, but you could try wrapping `require('socketcan')` in a try/catch.

Comment: I use this workaround, but... i don't know if its the proper way. I want to use es6 imports... to be consistent.